# SQL query to find gross and net % out of subscription time consumed

Tags: sql

I need to check net and gross percentages out of minutes consumed by agencies which have a subscription hour count. The tables keep the minutes consumed by each agencie but if the "nocomp_ta" collumn value is "1" it goes to the gross, if it is "0" it goes to net(chargable hours).  If the collumn habilitated is "1" it does not go in the metric.  My problem is that I cannot seem to make it work, no error is thrown but the results are not right. I am using Heidi sql for the tests.

```
SELECT 
( SUM( times.times_minutes ) / 60 ) AS Gross,
( SUM( times.times_minutes ) / 60 * 100 ) / agencies.subscription AS GrossPercent,
( _tt.net / 60 ) AS Net,
( ( _tt.net / 60 )*100 ) / agencies.subscription AS NetPercent,
times.time_minutes,
times.time_task,
times.time_agencie,
tasks_tiemes.code_t,
tasks_tiemes.nocomp_ta,
agencias.EMP_CODE,
agencias.EMP_NAME,
agencies.subscription,
agencies.habilitated
FROM times

INNER JOIN agencies 
ON agencies.EMP_CODE = times.time_agencie

INNER JOIN tasks_times
ON tasks_times.nocomp_ta = 0 AND times.time_task = tasks_times.code_t

LEFT JOIN  (SELECT 
( SUM( times.time_minutes ) / 60 ) AS net,
times.time_date,
times.time_minutes,
agencies.EMP_CODE,
agencies.habilitaed 
FROM times
INNER JOIN agencies
ON agencies.EMP_CODE = times.time_agencie
INNER JOIN tasks_times 
ON tasks_times.nocomp_ta = 1 AND times.time_task = tasks_times.code_t
WHERE 
agencies.habilitated = 0 AND  
AND YEAR( times.time_date ) BETWEEN '2013' AND '2013' 
AND MONTH( times.time_date ) BETWEEN '5' AND '5' 
GROUP BY times.time_agencie) _tt
ON _tt.EMP_CODE = times.time_agencie

WHERE

agencies.habilitated = 0
AND YEAR( times.time_date ) BETWEEN '2013' AND '2013'
AND MONTH( times.time_date ) BETWEEN '5' AND '5'

GROUP BY times.time_agencie
```

Comment: what result are you getting, and what's your expected result ? Show us some sql fiddle and example data so we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a join when you maybe want a union (to cover the different calculation cases of `nocomp_ta` - but you could perhaps do it in one query with something like :

```
 select 
 (SUM(time.time_minutes * tasks_time.nocomp_ta)) as net,
 (SUM(time.time_minutes *  (1 - tasks_time.nocomp_ta))) as gross
 ...
```